# How are bids packages and awards generated?

Tags: airline-operations, crew, airline-pilot, flight-attendant

There probably is no short answer for this. Crews out there, how do you bid and how are you rewarded? Are you always satisfied with your lines? Can someone also explain in brief from a system point of view, if you happen to be a crewscheduler. Thanks

Comment: This looks like 3 different questions that would get better answers if asked individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This differs from airline to airline, at a large ME carrier the staff is divided in groups based on their personality. People from each group are randomly assigned to flights. Then there is a list where you're at a certain position, with each flight you take you move one spot higher on the list. The higher you are on this list the more they will take your preference for a flight into account. Lets say that this list has 7 positions, once you've hit the top you are moved back to the bottom of this list. Then with each flight you're going one step up in the list again. So after each 7 flights you have the flight of your preference. But say that you're almost at the bottom and file a preference for a very unpopular flight then you have a high change they will schedule you on that flight.